# Print function using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, printing

I will make this fairly quick as it's a very simple question. How do I make a slot in Qt that prints out everything inside of my text editor. Simply a print button that behaves as you'd expect a print button to behave. I'm reading about a QPrintDialog, but I can't get it to work. This is what I tried:

```
QPrintDialog printDialog(printer, this);
if(printDialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted){
    ui->textBox->print(printer);
}
```

I tried doing QPrinter *printer = new QPrinter before it... but that gave me all sorts of errors, which I kind of figured it would. I already have #include QPrintDialog so how do I actually get this to work? Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Edit: I was looking for an answer for my question and I found a code that seems to be closer to working if that makes sense.

QPrinter printer;

```
QPrintDialog *printDialog = new QPrintDialog(&printer, this);
printDialog->setWindowTitle("Print Document");
if (printDialog->exec() != QDialog::Accepted)
         return;
```

However, now I get an error that says:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\C++ Projects\Qt Gui Applications\WordWrite-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug\..\WordWrite\wordwritemain.cpp:130: error: aggregate 'QPrinter printer' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

Comment: What exactly are those "all sorts of errors"?

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\C++ Projects\Qt Gui Applications\WordWrite-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug\..\WordWrite\wordwritemain.cpp:132: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QPrinter'

Comment: c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include\QtGui\qwindowdefs.h:81: error: forward declaration of 'struct QPrinter'                                                           C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\C++ Projects\Qt Gui Applications\WordWrite-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug\..\WordWrite\wordwritemain.cpp:133: error: no matching function for call to 'QPrintDialog::QPrintDialog(QPrinter**, WordWriteMain* const)'

Comment: Sorry about the spacing, but there are three errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the answer to the question on the help part of the Nokia website. the code I used was:

```
QPrinter printer;
QPrintDialog *printDialog = new QPrintDialog(&printer, this);
printDialog->setWindowTitle("Print Document");
if (printDialog->exec() != QDialog::Accepted){
    ui->textBox->print(&printer);
}
```

Which is basically what I was doing before except:

- I added &printer instead of printer

`- I added #include <QPrinter>`

Thanks for the help anyway, and I hope this helps future text editor developers.